# Retain the form in a gravity form confirmation

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

During gravity form confirmation (after form is successfully filled up and user submits the form) instead of showing only the confirmation text, I would also like to display the confirmation text and the form itself also, below the confirmation text.

I can't use the redirect to page url or page options on the confirmation settings of a gform, coz the user is using the form on various pages via shortcode (some of em are even hard coded via do_shortcode), and he is planning to add more.

The idea is, after the user fills up and submits the form ( no matter what page the form is residing ), the form data would get submitted, page reloaded, a confirmation message is displayed and the actual form is displayed too (of course all data gone, fresh state)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter' , "foo" , 10 , 1 );

function foo ( $form ) {

    global $post;

    // Get current page url
    $current_page_url = get_post_permalink( $post->ID );

    if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmations' , $form ) ) {

        foreach ( $form[ 'confirmations' ] as $key => $confirmation ) {

            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'type' ] = 'redirect';
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'message' ] = '';
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'url' ] = $current_page_url;
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'queryString' ] = 'message=Form Data Saved';

        }

    }

    if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmation' , $form ) ) {

        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'type' ] = 'redirect';
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'message' ] = '';
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'url' ] = $current_page_url;
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'queryString' ] = 'message=Form Data Saved';

    }

    return $form;

}
```

Hook into the **gform_pre_submission_filter** filter, the callback for that hook will receive the **$form** variable.

**$form** is an array which contains details for how it handles it confirmation as a sub array.

It has 2, **$form['confirmations']**, contains all the confirmations registered for this particular gform.

**$form['confirmation']**, contains data of the **"Default Confirmation"** to use. Change both, in my case I change it to **'redirect'** type then supplied the url to redirect.

I added a query string data too, its ok to add spaces here, gform will take care of the escaping.

This is tested on a gform with only 1 confirmation, which is the **Default Confirmation.**

This is also tested on a page where it contains only 1 gform.

If you have a page with multiple gforms, its easy, just add the id of the gform in question to the queryString. Then its much easier to extract the query string and identify which gform a confirmation message pertains to.

You can get the current gform's id via **$form['id']**

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: A bit late to the party, this is everything I need except that it doesn't display the confirmation message after submission...is there a solution for this?

Comment: Same problem here too. Confirmation message doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Jplus2 is missing a `return $form;` at the end of the function.

I've also found an easier solution by adding a shortcode to the message:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter' , "foo_show_confirmation_and_form" , 10 , 1 );
function foo_show_confirmation_and_form($form) {
  $shortcode = '[gravityform id="' . $form['id'] . '" title="true" description="false"]';

  if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmations' , $form ) ) {
    foreach ( $form[ 'confirmations' ] as $key => $confirmation ) {
      $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'message' ] .= $shortcode;
    }
  }

  if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmation' , $form ) ) {
    $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'message' ] .= $shortcode;
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: A bit late comment but I've updated my answer to return $form. Thanks for the pick up.