# Display gravity forms confirmation after reload

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm needing to keep a gravity form visible after submission.

I understand this is not a default option for some reason but have found that I can add a redirect function to the current page using the answer to a similar question:

[Retain the form in a gravity form confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406412/retain-the-form-in-a-gravity-form-confirmation)

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter' , "foo" , 10 , 1 );

function foo ( $form ) {

    global $post;

    // Get current page url
    $current_page_url = get_post_permalink( $post->ID );

    if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmations' , $form ) ) {

        foreach ( $form[ 'confirmations' ] as $key => $confirmation ) {

            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'type' ] = 'redirect';
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'message' ] = '';
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'url' ] = $current_page_url;
            $form[ 'confirmations' ][ $key ][ 'queryString' ] = 'message=Form Data Saved';

        }

    }

    if ( array_key_exists( 'confirmation' , $form ) ) {

        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'type' ] = 'redirect';
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'message' ] = '';
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'url' ] = $current_page_url;
        $form[ 'confirmation' ][ 'queryString' ] = 'message=Form Data Saved';

    }

    return $form;

}
```

However, this doesn't display the confirmation message after redirect.

Can someone help me edit this function to display the confirmation after redirect?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for but GF Reload Form could show the confirmation for a few seconds and then automatically reload the form. Alternately, you could include a link in the confirmation that reloads the form (via JS not a slow full page reload): https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-reload-form/

Comment: @DavefromGravityWiz I'm asking because I'm finding GF to be quite limiting for a particular client. They're needing the form to have a modal popup confirmation and for the form to simply remain visible after submission. So many websites have this. For some reason, GF does not offer what seems to be standard.

Comment: Do you have a URL where I could see this on a website? I'm not sure I'm familiar with this form pattern.

Comment: I've ended up just using a redirect button in the confirmation message. This reloads the page without submitting the form again. Seems to do the trick for what I'm needing.